# setup gunicorn to run with systemd

Tags: django, gunicorn, digital-ocean

Trying to set up `gunicorn` to run with `systemd`.  The control file is `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` and the output for testing is

```
root@samuel-pc:~# systemctl start gunicorn
Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gunicorn.service' for details.


root@samuel-pc:~# systemctl status gunicorn.service
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 29 05:13:17 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 05:13:17 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 29 05:13:29 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 05:13:29 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 29 05:15:45 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 05:15:45 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 29 07:01:10 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 07:01:10 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Jun 29 07:01:55 samuel-pc systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:9] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp
Jun 29 07:01:55 samuel-pc systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

which shows the error starts in line 9 of the gunicorn service because of the `ExecStart`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/revamp
ExecStart=gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 12):

It's telling you that it doesn't want a relative path for the `gunicorn` executable:
`Executable path is not absolute, ignoring`.

You need to change it to the absolute path of your `gunicorn` executable, either:

- System's executable: `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn`
- Your virtual environment's executable: `ExecStart=/path/to/venv/bin/gunicorn`

You can check this gist: [Using Systemd to Make Sure Gunicorn Starts on Boot](https://gist.github.com/marcanuy/5ae0e0ef5976aa4a10a7), for a minimal gunicorn systemd service config file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I believe this solved this problem, now I'm getting a `excess arguments` error

Comment: can you post the log?