# How to solve the error "Executable path is not absolute, ignoring:"

Tags: django, gunicorn, amazon-linux-2

I'm currently developing an application in `Amazon Linux2` using `Django`, `Nginx`, `Gunicorn`, and `Postgresql`.

I have created and configured a system file for `Gunicorn` to work when the OS boots, But after starting `gunicorn` I get the following error...

> Jun 08 18:18:04 ip-172-31-16-86.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]:
> [/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:10] Executable path is not
> absolute, ignoring: gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind
> unix:/home/myname/django_project/django_project.sock ......

> Jun 08 18:18:04 ip-172-31-16-86.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]:
> gunicorn.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting.
> Refusing.

I'm sure the absolute path specified in the file is correct, but I get the error.

How could I solve this problem?

*NOTE:
`Amazon Linux2` doesn't include `www-data` groups, so I created using `groupadd` command.

---

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
 
 
[Service]
User=myname
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myname/django_project
ExecStart=/home/myname/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myname/django_project/django_project.sock django_project.wsgi:application
 
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Directory structure

```
home
 │
 └─myname
    │
    ├─django_project
    │    ├─django_project
    │    ├─manage.py
    │    └─django_project.sock
    │  
    └─venv
         └─bin
            └─gunicorn
```

---

OS Amazon Linux2

gunicorn 20.1.0

boto 2.49.0

Django 3.2.4

django-ses 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully others will be have better answers or suggestions but [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818451/setup-gunicorn-to-run-with-systemd) emphasizes to double check the existence of the path to the Gunicorn executable or making sure your environment recognizes that.

[This discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/1425478/django-gunicorn-service-not-working-got-error-failed-at-step-exec-spawning-pat) also further emphasizes checking everything is installed correctly